# How does one unhide a lost hidden sheet?

Tags: tableau-api

### Setup:

I know how to navigate to a hidden sheet from a dashboard and select "Unhide Sheet" by right-clicking on the temporarily revealed sheet's tab.  The [online documentation](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v8.0/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#environ_workbooksandsheets_sheets_hideshow.html) from Tableau's website is clear enough.

### Question:

However, how can I unhide the sheet if it isn't a part of a dashboard?  Put another way, how can I navigate to a hidden sheet if it was hidden before it was added to a dashboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tableau will not allow you to hide a sheet if it is not a part of at least one dashboard.  Looking at your dashboard tabs, it may not be immediately clear where the sheet is, but it is there.

You may need to look at the list of sheets in the Dashboard Side Bar for each dashboard, one-by-one, until you find the sheet in question.  If the Dashboard Sidebar is not showing, or if you're not certain what it looks like, click "Window" at the top of your Desktop Edition and see to it that "Show Side Bar" has a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove a sheet from a dashboard without unhiding it, or deleting it:

[image: Prompt when removing a hidden sheet from a dashboard]

And, the option to hide a sheet which is not part of a dashboard is not available.

By using the tabs in the top right of Tableau Desktop, it may be more easy to identify the sheet which is thought to be hidden